# How does aspect influence static method in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, aop

```
public class Secured {
    @RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
    public static void staticJsr250() {
        System.out.println("@RolesAllowed in static");
        System.out.println("The class is: " + new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingClass());
    }
}
```

---

Without role ADMIN, the method won't output anything.

With role ADMIN, it will output:

```
@RolesAllowed in static
The class is: class Secured
```

I don't know why it works.

For non-static method, it should work because the implicit parameter is a proxy, instead of a truely Secured object.

But there is proxy for static method?

How to explain it?

Comment: What makes you think it should only work on non-static classes? What do you mean by "implicit parameter"? And where is the connection to AOP?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, I hope you know what I mean.
Spring AOP is built around dynamic proxies.

Non-static method:
`@Inject Car c;
#####
c.method();`
#####
"c" is the implict parameter.
Here c is not a true Car Object, but a proxy of Car Object. So Spring can "insert" something before the method invoked.
==========
Static method:
`Car.staticMethod();`
#####
So where is "proxy" here? The "proxy" is for what? There is even no object here.

Comment: I am not a Spring user, but an AspectJ expert. Still I know how Spring AOP works. But what I cannot tell you is if Spring Security internally uses Spring AOP or not. Maybe your assumption that is just wrong and it works differently. That was what I meant. Maybe Spring Security is just not proxy-based.

Comment: This is a resonable explaination. I think you're right, thanks.